# Error when reading '../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-5.1.0/lib/win32.dart': Permission denied

Tags: flutter, dart

this is error

`Failed to build flutterfire_cli:flutterfire:
../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/dart_console-1.2.0/lib/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart:13:8: Error: Error when reading '../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-5.1.0/lib/win32.dart': Permission denied
import 'package:win32/win32.dart';
^
../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/dart_console-1.2.0/lib/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart:35:22: Error: The getter 'ENABLE_ECHO_INPUT' isn't defined for the class 'TermLibWindows'.

- 'TermLibWindows' is from 'package:dart_console/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart' ('../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/dart_console-1.2.0/lib/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'ENABLE_ECHO_INPUT'.
  final dwMode = (~ENABLE_ECHO_INPUT) &
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/dart_console-1.2.0/lib/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart:36:11: Error: The getter 'ENABLE_PROCESSED_INPUT' isn't defined for the class 'TermLibWindows'.
- 'TermLibWindows' is from 'package:dart_console/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart' ('../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/dart_console-1.2.0/lib/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'ENABLE_PROCESSED_INPUT'.
  (~ENABLE_PROCESSED_INPUT) &
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/dart_console-1.2.0/lib/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart:37:11: Error: The getter 'ENABLE_LINE_INPUT' isn't defined for the class 'TermLibWindows'.
- 'TermLibWindows' is from 'package:dart_console/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart' ('../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/dart_console-1.2.0/lib/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'ENABLE_LINE_INPUT'.
  (~ENABLE_LINE_INPUT) &
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/dart_console-1.2.0/lib/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart:38:11: Error: The getter 'ENABLE_WINDOW_INPUT' isn't defined for the class 'TermLibWindows'.
- 'TermLibWindows' is from 'package:dart_console/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart' ('../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/dart_console-1.2.0/lib/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'ENABLE_WINDOW_INPUT'.
  (~ENABLE_WINDOW_INPUT);
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/dart_console-1.2.0/lib/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart:39:5: Error: The method 'SetConsoleMode' isn't defined for the class 'TermLibWindows'.
- 'TermLibWindows' is from 'package:dart_console/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart' ('../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/dart_console-1.2.0/lib/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'SetConsoleMode'.
  SetConsoleMode(inputHandle, dwMode);
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/dart_console-1.2.0/lib/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart:44:20: Error: The getter 'ENABLE_ECHO_INPUT' isn't defined for the class 'TermLibWindows'.
- 'TermLibWindows' is from 'package:dart_console/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart' ('../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/dart_console-1.2.0/lib/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'ENABLE_ECHO_INPUT'.
  final dwMode = ENABLE_ECHO_INPUT &
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/dart_console-1.2.0/lib/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart:45:9: Error: The getter 'ENABLE_EXTENDED_FLAGS' isn't defined for the class 'TermLibWindows'.
- 'TermLibWindows' is from 'package:dart_console/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart' ('../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/dart_console-1.2.0/lib/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'ENABLE_EXTENDED_FLAGS'.
  ENABLE_EXTENDED_FLAGS &
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/dart_console-1.2.0/lib/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart:46:9: Error: The getter 'ENABLE_INSERT_MODE' isn't defined for the class 'TermLibWindows'.
- 'TermLibWindows' is from 'package:dart_console/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart' ('../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/dart_console-1.2.0/lib/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'ENABLE_INSERT_MODE'.
  ENABLE_INSERT_MODE &
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/dart_console-1.2.0/lib/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart:47:9: Error: The getter 'ENABLE_LINE_INPUT' isn't defined for the class 'TermLibWindows'.
- 'TermLibWindows' is from 'package:dart_console/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart' ('../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/dart_console-1.2.0/lib/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'ENABLE_LINE_INPUT'.
  ENABLE_LINE_INPUT &
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/dart_console-1.2.0/lib/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart:48:9: Error: The getter 'ENABLE_MOUSE_INPUT' isn't defined for the class 'TermLibWindows'.
- 'TermLibWindows' is from 'package:dart_console/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart' ('../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/dart_console-1.2.0/lib/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'ENABLE_MOUSE_INPUT'.
  ENABLE_MOUSE_INPUT &
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/dart_console-1.2.0/lib/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart:49:9: Error: The getter 'ENABLE_PROCESSED_INPUT' isn't defined for the class 'TermLibWindows'.
- 'TermLibWindows' is from 'package:dart_console/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart' ('../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/dart_console-1.2.0/lib/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'ENABLE_PROCESSED_INPUT'.
  ENABLE_PROCESSED_INPUT &
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/dart_console-1.2.0/lib/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart:50:9: Error: The getter 'ENABLE_QUICK_EDIT_MODE' isn't defined for the class 'TermLibWindows'.
- 'TermLibWindows' is from 'package:dart_console/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart' ('../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/dart_console-1.2.0/lib/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'ENABLE_QUICK_EDIT_MODE'.
  ENABLE_QUICK_EDIT_MODE &
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/dart_console-1.2.0/lib/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart:51:9: Error: The getter 'ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_INPUT' isn't defined for the class 'TermLibWindows'.
- 'TermLibWindows' is from 'package:dart_console/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart' ('../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/dart_console-1.2.0/lib/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_INPUT'.
  ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_INPUT;
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/dart_console-1.2.0/lib/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart:52:5: Error: The method 'SetConsoleMode' isn't defined for the class 'TermLibWindows'.
- 'TermLibWindows' is from 'package:dart_console/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart' ('../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/dart_console-1.2.0/lib/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'SetConsoleMode'.
  SetConsoleMode(inputHandle, dwMode);
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/dart_console-1.2.0/lib/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart:56:40: Error: 'CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO' isn't a type.
  final lpConsoleCursorInfo = calloc<CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO>()..ref.bVisible = 0;
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/dart_console-1.2.0/lib/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart:56:64: Error: The property 'ref' is defined in multiple extensions for 'Pointer' and neither is more specific.
- 'Pointer' is from 'dart:ffi'.
  Try using an explicit extension application of the wanted extension or hiding unwanted extensions from scope.
  final lpConsoleCursorInfo = calloc<CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO>()..ref.bVisible = 0;
  ^^^
  ../../Library/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/vm/lib/ffi_patch.dart:1133:9: Context: This is one of the extension members.
  T get ref =>
  ^^^
  ../../Library/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/vm/lib/ffi_patch.dart:1156:9: Context: This is one of the extension members.
  T get ref =>
  ^^^
  ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/dart_console-1.2.0/lib/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart:58:7: Error: The method 'SetConsoleCursorInfo' isn't defined for the class 'TermLibWindows'.
- 'TermLibWindows' is from 'package:dart_console/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart' ('../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/dart_console-1.2.0/lib/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'SetConsoleCursorInfo'.
  SetConsoleCursorInfo(outputHandle, lpConsoleCursorInfo);
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/dart_console-1.2.0/lib/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart:65:40: Error: 'CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO' isn't a type.
  final lpConsoleCursorInfo = calloc<CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO>()..ref.bVisible = 1;
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/dart_console-1.2.0/lib/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart:65:64: Error: The property 'ref' is defined in multiple extensions for 'Pointer' and neither is more specific.
- 'Pointer' is from 'dart:ffi'.
  Try using an explicit extension application of the wanted extension or hiding unwanted extensions from scope.
  final lpConsoleCursorInfo = calloc<CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO>()..ref.bVisible = 1;
  ^^^
  ../../Library/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/vm/lib/ffi_patch.dart:1133:9: Context: This is one of the extension members.
  T get ref =>
  ^^^
  ../../Library/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/vm/lib/ffi_patch.dart:1156:9: Context: This is one of the extension members.
  T get ref =>
  ^^^
  ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/dart_console-1.2.0/lib/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart:67:7: Error: The method 'SetConsoleCursorInfo' isn't defined for the class 'TermLibWindows'.
- 'TermLibWindows' is from 'package:dart_console/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart' ('../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/dart_console-1.2.0/lib/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'SetConsoleCursorInfo'.
  SetConsoleCursorInfo(outputHandle, lpConsoleCursorInfo);
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/dart_console-1.2.0/lib/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart:74:32: Error: 'CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO' isn't a type.
  final pBufferInfo = calloc<CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO>();
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/dart_console-1.2.0/lib/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart:76:27: Error: 'COORD' isn't a type.
  final origin = calloc();
  ^^^^^
  ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/dart_console-1.2.0/lib/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart:78:38: Error: The property 'ref' is defined in multiple extensions for 'Pointer' and neither is more specific.
- 'Pointer' is from 'dart:ffi'.
  Try using an explicit extension application of the wanted extension or hiding unwanted extensions from scope.
  final bufferInfo = pBufferInfo.ref;
  ^^^
  ../../Library/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/vm/lib/ffi_patch.dart:1133:9: Context: This is one of the extension members.
  T get ref =>
  ^^^
  ../../Library/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/vm/lib/ffi_patch.dart:1156:9: Context: This is one of the extension members.
  T get ref =>
  ^^^
  ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/dart_console-1.2.0/lib/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart:79:7: Error: The method 'GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo' isn't defined for the class 'TermLibWindows'.
- 'TermLibWindows' is from 'package:dart_console/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart' ('../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/dart_console-1.2.0/lib/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo'.
  GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(outputHandle, pBufferInfo);
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/dart_console-1.2.0/lib/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart:83:7: Error: The method 'FillConsoleOutputCharacter' isn't defined for the class 'TermLibWindows'.
- 'TermLibWindows' is from 'package:dart_console/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart' ('../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/dart_console-1.2.0/lib/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'FillConsoleOutputCharacter'.
  FillConsoleOutputCharacter(outputHandle, ' '.codeUnitAt(0), consoleSize,
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/dart_console-1.2.0/lib/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart:84:18: Error: The property 'ref' is defined in multiple extensions for 'Pointer' and neither is more specific.
- 'Pointer' is from 'dart:ffi'.
  Try using an explicit extension application of the wanted extension or hiding unwanted extensions from scope.
  origin.ref, pCharsWritten);
  ^^^
  ../../Library/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/vm/lib/ffi_patch.dart:1133:9: Context: This is one of the extension members.
  T get ref =>
  ^^^
  ../../Library/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/vm/lib/ffi_patch.dart:1156:9: Context: This is one of the extension members.
  T get ref =>
  ^^^
  ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/dart_console-1.2.0/lib/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart:86:7: Error: The method 'GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo' isn't defined for the class 'TermLibWindows'.
- 'TermLibWindows' is from 'package:dart_console/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart' ('../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/dart_console-1.2.0/lib/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo'.
  GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(outputHandle, pBufferInfo);
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/dart_console-1.2.0/lib/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart:88:7: Error: The method 'FillConsoleOutputAttribute' isn't defined for the class 'TermLibWindows'.
- 'TermLibWindows' is from 'package:dart_console/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart' ('../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/dart_console-1.2.0/lib/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'FillConsoleOutputAttribute'.
  FillConsoleOutputAttribute(outputHandle, bufferInfo.wAttributes,
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/dart_console-1.2.0/lib/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart:89:31: Error: The property 'ref' is defined in multiple extensions for 'Pointer' and neither is more specific.
- 'Pointer' is from 'dart:ffi'.
  Try using an explicit extension application of the wanted extension or hiding unwanted extensions from scope.
  consoleSize, origin.ref, pCharsWritten);
  ^^^
  ../../Library/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/vm/lib/ffi_patch.dart:1133:9: Context: This is one of the extension members.
  T get ref =>
  ^^^
  ../../Library/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/vm/lib/ffi_patch.dart:1156:9: Context: This is one of the extension members.
  T get ref =>
  ^^^
  ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/dart_console-1.2.0/lib/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart:91:7: Error: The method 'SetConsoleCursorPosition' isn't defined for the class 'TermLibWindows'.
- 'TermLibWindows' is from 'package:dart_console/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart' ('../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/dart_console-1.2.0/lib/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'SetConsoleCursorPosition'.
  SetConsoleCursorPosition(outputHandle, origin.ref);
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/dart_console-1.2.0/lib/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart:91:53: Error: The property 'ref' is defined in multiple extensions for 'Pointer' and neither is more specific.
- 'Pointer' is from 'dart:ffi'.
  Try using an explicit extension application of the wanted extension or hiding unwanted extensions from scope.
  SetConsoleCursorPosition(outputHandle, origin.ref);
  ^^^
  ../../Library/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/vm/lib/ffi_patch.dart:1133:9: Context: This is one of the extension members.
  T get ref =>
  ^^^
  ../../Library/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/vm/lib/ffi_patch.dart:1156:9: Context: This is one of the extension members.
  T get ref =>
  ^^^
  ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/dart_console-1.2.0/lib/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart:101:26: Error: 'COORD' isn't a type.
  final coord = calloc()
  ^^^^^
  ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/dart_console-1.2.0/lib/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart:102:9: Error: The property 'ref' is defined in multiple extensions for 'Pointer' and neither is more specific.
- 'Pointer' is from 'dart:ffi'.
  Try using an explicit extension application of the wanted extension or hiding unwanted extensions from scope.
  ..ref.X = x
  ^^^
  ../../Library/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/vm/lib/ffi_patch.dart:1133:9: Context: This is one of the extension members.
  T get ref =>
  ^^^
  ../../Library/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/vm/lib/ffi_patch.dart:1156:9: Context: This is one of the extension members.
  T get ref =>
  ^^^
  ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/dart_console-1.2.0/lib/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart:103:9: Error: The property 'ref' is defined in multiple extensions for 'Pointer' and neither is more specific.
- 'Pointer' is from 'dart:ffi'.
  Try using an explicit extension application of the wanted extension or hiding unwanted extensions from scope.
  ..ref.Y = y;
  ^^^
  ../../Library/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/vm/lib/ffi_patch.dart:1133:9: Context: This is one of the extension members.
  T get ref =>
  ^^^
  ../../Library/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/vm/lib/ffi_patch.dart:1156:9: Context: This is one of the extension members.
  T get ref =>
  ^^^
  ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/dart_console-1.2.0/lib/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart:105:7: Error: The method 'SetConsoleCursorPosition' isn't defined for the class 'TermLibWindows'.
- 'TermLibWindows' is from 'package:dart_console/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart' ('../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/dart_console-1.2.0/lib/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'SetConsoleCursorPosition'.
  SetConsoleCursorPosition(outputHandle, coord.ref);
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/dart_console-1.2.0/lib/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart:105:52: Error: The property 'ref' is defined in multiple extensions for 'Pointer' and neither is more specific.
- 'Pointer' is from 'dart:ffi'.
  Try using an explicit extension application of the wanted extension or hiding unwanted extensions from scope.
  SetConsoleCursorPosition(outputHandle, coord.ref);
  ^^^
  ../../Library/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/vm/lib/ffi_patch.dart:1133:9: Context: This is one of the extension members.
  T get ref =>
  ^^^
  ../../Library/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/vm/lib/ffi_patch.dart:1156:9: Context: This is one of the extension members.
  T get ref =>
  ^^^
  ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/dart_console-1.2.0/lib/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart:112:20: Error: The method 'GetStdHandle' isn't defined for the class 'TermLibWindows'.
- 'TermLibWindows' is from 'package:dart_console/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart' ('../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/dart_console-1.2.0/lib/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'GetStdHandle'.
  outputHandle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/dart_console-1.2.0/lib/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart:112:33: Error: The getter 'STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE' isn't defined for the class 'TermLibWindows'.
- 'TermLibWindows' is from 'package:dart_console/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart' ('../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/dart_console-1.2.0/lib/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE'.
  outputHandle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/dart_console-1.2.0/lib/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart:113:19: Error: The method 'GetStdHandle' isn't defined for the class 'TermLibWindows'.
- 'TermLibWindows' is from 'package:dart_console/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart' ('../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/dart_console-1.2.0/lib/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'GetStdHandle'.
  inputHandle = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/dart_console-1.2.0/lib/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart:113:32: Error: The getter 'STD_INPUT_HANDLE' isn't defined for the class 'TermLibWindows'.
- 'TermLibWindows' is from 'package:dart_console/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart' ('../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/dart_console-1.2.0/lib/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'STD_INPUT_HANDLE'.
  inputHandle = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/dart_console-1.2.0/lib/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart:56:39: Error: Expected type 'invalid-type' to be a valid and instantiated subtype of 'NativeType'.
  final lpConsoleCursorInfo = calloc<CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO>()..ref.bVisible = 0;
  ^
  ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/dart_console-1.2.0/lib/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart:65:39: Error: Expected type 'invalid-type' to be a valid and instantiated subtype of 'NativeType'.
  final lpConsoleCursorInfo = calloc<CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO>()..ref.bVisible = 1;
  ^
  ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/dart_console-1.2.0/lib/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart:74:31: Error: Expected type 'invalid-type' to be a valid and instantiated subtype of 'NativeType'.
  final pBufferInfo = calloc<CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO>();
  ^
  ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/dart_console-1.2.0/lib/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart:76:26: Error: Expected type 'invalid-type' to be a valid and instantiated subtype of 'NativeType'.
  final origin = calloc();
  ^
  ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/dart_console-1.2.0/lib/src/ffi/win/termlib_win.dart:101:25: Error: Expected type 'invalid-type' to be a valid and instantiated subtype of 'NativeType'.
  final coord = calloc()`